# How do I hide a block module on a single node with hook_page_alter?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a block module called share_page.

I have looked in the $page array and sure enough I have the region 'content', where this module always resides (but it is set not show on some pages).

This is the function I have in a .module file

```
function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) {
  unset($page['content']['share_page']['#block']);
}
```

The error thrown is: Undefined index: share_page in mymodule_page_alter()

But the block module (share_page) does not disappear. Does anyone know how I can hide this module?...and, also, hide it on just one particular page?

Answer (score 0):

**Partial solution:**

```
unset($page['content']['share_page_share_page']);
```

...but this removes it from all pages on the site - not sure how you target a single node?